# What is a parallel edge in Gephi and how do I deal with them when importing an edgelist?

Tags: gephi

When I import my .gexf file, it flags a bunch of parallel edges. I don't know what parallel edges are and why there's an issue with my graph. I'm trying to create a dynamic gephi graph.

[image]

Answer (score 13):

If you have several edges between one pair of two nodes, these edges are parallel to each other, so they are the parallel edges.

There is no way to represent parallel edges in Gephi.
So the Gephi will automatically merge your parallel edges into one edge. 
(But fortunately the weight will be also merged, e.g. if you put 3 parallel edges, the weight of new merged edge will be the sum of weights of given 3 parallel edges.)