# Import multigraph into Gephi from GML format

Tags: networkx, gephi, graphml

I use NetworkX to create a set of nodes and edges and export them into GML format so that I can view them on Gephi 0.9.1 version. When I import the following GML:

```
graph [
  multigraph 1
  directed 0
  node [
    id 0
    label 1
  ]
  node [
    id 1
    label 2
  ]
  edge [
    source 0
    target 1
    key "rel2"
  ]
  edge [
    source 0
    target 1
    key "rel1"
  ]
]
```

Gephi shows the following popup:
[image: Import multigraph into gephi]

It said `Multi Graph: no` while in the GML it is stated `multigraph 1`.
Gephi automatically merges the edges, and sets the weight to `2`, as below:

[image: Weight = 2]

How can I configure Gephi to read a multigraph? Should I change my GML or any settings in Gephi? Or it is a bug?

Answer (score 1):

> How can I configure gephi to read multigraph?

Parallel edges can not be displayed by Gephi ([will be merged unconditionally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17074313/what-is-a-parallel-edge-in-gephi-and-how-do-i-deal-with-them-when-importing-an-e/18058704#18058704)).

Comment: I change 'directed 0' to 'directed 1' in the gml above. Still the same. Gephi merges two edges, set key to 'rel2'

Comment: OK. looks like this is a missing feature.

Comment: It will be fixed in upcoming versions though